# Trying to create an async validator using pipe/map

Tags: angular, typescript

The ideia is simple. I have an input where the user enters a string. I would like to be able to validate it. I managed to do it with SetTimeout and a simple if/else logic but I would like to understand how pipe/map can help work in this case.

this is what I came up with so far, but instead of having only `test2` be invalid, I'm getting my name always as invalid. I'm probably getting the logic wrong somewhere

```
 asyncInvalidProjectName(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    return of(control.value).pipe(
      map(value => value === 'test2' ? { 'invalidProjectName': true } : null),
      delay(500)
    );
  }
```

Comment: How do you pass this validator ? If you pass an async validator as a validator you will always get  `invalid`.

Comment: I passed it in the validators array. I'm using reactive forms so my form is in my .ts file. I created on before, passed it as a Validator and it worked

Comment: Beware FormControl takes 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async validators are a separate category from validators. If you're using FormBuilder, then it's, for example,

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    foo: ['initial value', null, this.asyncInvalidProjectName],
});
```

and with FormControl constructor it would be

```
const control = new FormControl('initial value', {
   asyncValidators: this.asyncInvalidProjectName,
});
```

Comment: So from what I understand async validators need to be passed differently in my FormGroup. I'm using FormControl in this case and was passing it like this: 
```'projectName': new FormControl(null,
         [Validators.required,
          this.invalidProjectName.bind(this),//regular validator
           this.asyncInvalidProjectName//async validator
          ]
           )```

Is this what's wrong and not my logic?

Comment: This managed to help me figure out, thanks a lot! I just passed the async validator outside of the regular validators array. No need for the ```asyncValidators:```